What is another way to correctly get the current activity in an android emulator
I am trying to use the Acvitity method for my android test.
public void setActivity() {         
    Activity activity =  new Activity("com.androidsample.generalstore","com.androidsample.generalstore.MainActivity");
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("mobile: startActivity", ImmutableMap
            .of("intent", "com.androidsample.generalstore/com.androidsample.generalstore.MainActivity"));     
}

@BeforeMethod(enabled = true)     
public void preSetup() {         //screen to homepage         
    formPage.setActivity();     
}

adb shell dumpsys window | find "mCurrentFocus"   mCurrentFocus=Window{38760a4 u0 com.androidsample.generalstore/com.androidsample.generalstore.MainActivity}
I keep getting an error saying

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C:\Users\Irvin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell am start-activity com.androidsample.generalstore/com.androidsample.generalstore.MainActivity' exited with code 255'; Command output:
Exception occurred while executing 'start-activity':`

I have tried using the old version to do this but the method has depricated and no longer works. Anyone know the fix to this?

Your code is not well-formatted and is not readable, something that you should have seen and fixed prior to posting, no?

I have tried to clean up your question's formatting, but again, this is something that you should be putting in the effort to do yourself.

My apologies. I am not sure why it came out that way I am new to posting on stack overflow. I will be more careful next time and thank you.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can use the startactivity() method directly in appium2.0 to launch any activity .Need not to use javascript executor here
public void setActivity() {         
Activity activity = new Activity("com.androidsample.generalstore", "com.androidsample.generalstore.MainActivity");
driver.startActivity(activity); 

}

the .startActivity() method is depricated and no longer works sadly.
